# ReactNative Display different font of text based on a JSON type attribute

Tags: css, react-native

I am working on a mobile app to display my school's lunch options, I've parsed the data using the code below:

```
  async function fetchData() {
    fetch(apiLunchURL)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        setJSON_DATA(responseJson);
        setShowIndicator(false);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }
```

The code works, and [my app displays this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trFBU.png) However I'd like my title to be seperated better, here is a snippet of the JSON database I'm working with.

```
    "type": "title",
    "text": "ENTREES"
  },
  {
    "type": "entry",
    "text": "Grilled Cheese Sandwich"
  },
  {
    "type": "entry",
    "text": "Gluten-Free Grilled Cheese Sandwich"
  },
  {
    "type": "entry",
    "text": "Vegan \"Pizza\" Grilled Cheese"
  },
  {
    "type": "title",
    "text": "SIDES"
  },
  {
    "type": "entry",
    "text": "Basil Pesto Pasta Shells"
  },
```

Right now here is the code I am using to render it:

```
<View style ={styles.lunchArea}>
                    <FlatList
                      data={JSON_DATA}
                      
                      renderItem={({ item }) =>( 
          
                        <View style={{paddingTop: 10, marginBottom: -10 }}>
                          <ItemRender title={item.text} />
                        </View>
                      )}
                      ItemSeparatorComponent={LunchDivider}
                      keyExtractor={item => item.id}

                    />
                  </View>
```

ItemRender Code:

```
const ItemRender = ({ title }) => (
    <View style={styles.listItem}>
      
      <Text style={styles.lunchItems}> {title} </Text>
    </View>
  );
```

As you can see the 'title' of each section is shown by a type attribute, rather than organization im more familiar with. How can I display text using different CSS profiles, with `title` being bigger and bold etc... and `entry` based on the type attribute?

Comment: How does your render function currently look like?

Comment: @DavidScholz just added it :)

Comment: Is `ItemRender` a custom component?

Comment: sorry just added that too 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since each object contains a `type` property which seems to be either `title` or `entry`, we could change the styling of the `Text` component inside the `ItemRender` component using conditional rendering. This could be implemented as follows:

```js
renderItem={({ item }) => (  
        <View style={{paddingTop: 10, marginBottom: -10 }}>
               <ItemRender title={item.text} type={item.type} />
        </View>
)}

const ItemRender = ({ title, type }) => (
    <View style={styles.listItem}>
      <Text style={type === 'entry' ? styles.lunchItems : styles.title}> {title} </Text>
    </View>
  );
```

In the above, we pass the type to the `ItemRender` component and conditionally change the style of the `Text` component depending on whether or not `type` is an `entry` or not.

Here are some example styles:

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  lunchItems: {
    fontSize: 12,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});
```

[Here is a short snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@pgrepds/intrigued-candies).

Comment: Thank you David my king  I'm new to react dev so it's so interesting to see how all this code is possible, thank you so much again!

Comment: You are very welcome! Good luck with your app :)